Ambiguous column name on a temporary Table in a join statement
I'm pulling data from a XML document with the following node structure (as in this is the structure of the node I'm using in this problem, I don't think the whole structure in relevant to solve this problem)
<empleado Puesto="Camarero" ValorDocumentoIdentidad="2156046" Nombre="Joe Ferguson" FechaContratacion="2023-01-19" />

PS: this is made up data so it isn't sensitive at all (Uni project)
From this XML I must replace 'Puesto' with its id which I pull from a table called dbo.Puesto which I link by the column called Nombre
(Name for the English speakers)
I'm using a temporary table since I'll just need this information once to insert it into a table, and I'm not doing anything else with it (I'm doing more with it but for that I'll use the table I'm inserting this information into).
My problem is that I'm getting the error:

Ambiguous column name 'Nombre'

on this following line
SELECT ValorDocumentoIdentidad, Nombre, FechaContratacion, dbo.Puesto.id

I have tried using an alias but it wont let me since this resulting table doesn't exist in the database as such (it's temporary, so it doesn't have a name).
What solution do you internet mages see in such a way that I can keep this information on a temporary table (if possible)?
I want to try and keep it on temporary table because I have more query's pulling info from the XML and I want to keep the same format, and not suddenly declare a table just for one piece of information
Code I'm testing:
DECLARE @xml XML,@hDoc INT;

SET @xml = (SELECT TOP(1) column1 
            FROM dbo.datos   
            ORDER BY column1 DESC)

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument  @hDoc OUTPUT, @xml

SELECT 
    ValorDocumentoIdentidad, Nombre, FechaContratacion, dbo.Puesto.id
FROM 
    OPENXML(@hDoc, '/Datos/Empleados/empleado')  
    WITH (  
            Puesto VARCHAR(128),
            ValorDocumentoIdentidad VARCHAR(64),
            Nombre VARCHAR(128),
            FechaContratacion DATE
         )
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Puesto ON Puesto = dbo.Puesto.Nombre


Alias your tables and alias reference every column you use. You clearly have a Nombre column in both your tables...

ohh now i see where my mistake was, many thanks Dale K

You don't need openxml here. Just use the nodes method. Openxml can only work with one XML and you have a table of rows where it becomes unfeasable. Google: xml nodes sql server

For the curious, turns out you can put an Alias on a temporary table, but with the structure of this query its goes after the with which is my first time seeing it in such a place
The resulting fixed code looks as follows:
SELECT a.ValorDocumentoIdentidad, a.Nombre, a.FechaContratacion, dbo.Puesto.id
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, '/Datos/Empleados/empleado')  
WITH   
(  
    Puesto VARCHAR(128)
    ,ValorDocumentoIdentidad VARCHAR(64)
    ,Nombre VARCHAR(128)
    ,FechaContratacion DATE
) AS a  --alias goes here
INNER JOIN dbo.Puesto ON a.Puesto = dbo.Puesto.Nombre


Best practice is to alias your real table also with a short alias, therefore not fully reference it everywhere e.g. dbo.Puesto AS p

Also don't use OPENXML it's ancient and has lots of problems. Use .nodes instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16
